# Make the playhead in DaVinci Resolve thinner

Tags: editing, davinci-resolve, playback

thank you for helping me! I'm currently learning the basics of DaVinci Resolve, coming from a way simpler program. But from that program, I'm used to a much thinner playhead. Is there a way to make the playhead thinner in DaVinci Resolve? I've of course searched on this site, on youtube and on the internet in general of course. Also, I've searched around in the program. Thank you for your help!

[image]

The relatively thick playhead

Comment: I would suggest that you will just need to get used to it. It's not a configurable item, as far as I'm aware. Why would you want it thinner? The line is the important bit anyway, and it's not like the head covers up anything critical - you get the exact time read-out anyway.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. I had the feeling it was thinner with others, but then I'll just get used to it.

Comment: The devs at blackmagic design are usually very receptive to feature requests on their user forums, especially if the community reaches consensus.  Try asking at https://forum.blackmagicdesign.com/viewforum.php?f=21